# Angular and CreateJS: iterating through an array for the beginFill variable

Tags: angular, createjs

I am working on creating a breakout game, and I would really like the colors of the blocks to vary depending on the row (top row red to bottom row blue). I am able to create the rows of bricks, but I cannot iterate over the fill colors to fill each row differently. Here is what I have:

Component:

```
import { Component, AfterViewInit } from '@angular/core';
import { NgClass } from '@angular/common';
import * as createjs from 'createjs-module';

@Component({
selector: 'breakout',
templateUrl: './breakout.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./breakout.component.scss']
})
export class BreakoutComponent implements AfterViewInit {
    canvas;
    ngAfterViewInit(){
        var stage = new createjs.Stage("canvas");
        var g = new createjs.Graphics();
        var x = 0;
        var y = 60;
        var rect =  new createjs.Shape(g);
            for(y; y < 120; y+=12){
                var fill = [
                    "red",
                    "orange",
                    "yellow",
                    "green",
                    "blue"
                ]
                var i = 0;
                g.beginFill(fill[i++]);
                for(x; x < 480; x += 42){
                    g.drawRect(x, y, 40, 10);
                }
                x = 0;
            }
        stage.addChild(rect)
        stage.update();
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

If you squares are all red, its because your fill list and `i` variable are inside your loop. Each loop iteration does the same thing, and starts over at 0:

```
for (...) {
    var fill = [
        "red",
        "orange",
        "yellow",
        "green",
        "blue"
    ];
    var i = 0;
    g.beginFill(fill[i++]); // Red fill
}
```

Instead, put your fill array outside of the loop (even at the top since it doesn't change during the loops), and then initialize your `i` variable there instead.

```
var fill = [
    "red",
    "orange",
    "yellow",
    "green",
    "blue"
];
var i = 0;
for (...) {
    g.beginFill(fill[i++]);
}
```

Also note that your `i` variable will be the length of your `for` loop (120/12), so you will get a bunch of undefined colors. In this case, I recommend either cycling your array (with %) or adding more colors, depending on what you are trying to do:

```
var index = i++ % fill.length; // 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4 (etc)
g.beginFill(fill[index]);
```

Hope that helps!